# Amount of bijective boolean fucntions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Could you explain how many bijective functions with that definition:

$ F : \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ ?

I think there is $2^{2n}$ functions.

If it's true, what the difference between cardinality for all functions and bijective functions? (for all function cardinality is equals to $2^{n2^{n}}$)

Comment: the amout of bijections between $\lbrace 0, 1 \rbrace^n$ and itself is actually $(2^n)!$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form of your domain and codomain don't matter; the only property which matters here is that they both have $2^n$ elements.

For bijective functions, note that any $F : \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ is specified by giving its value of each element in the domain. For its first value, there are $2^n$ choices. For the next, there are $2^n-1$ choices (since it must be injective!). I hope you see where this is going - to construct an injective map $F : \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ we have $2^n!$ choices. Conversely, each such map will also be surjective since the domain and the codomain have the same cardinality.

If you don't require $F$ to be bijective, you just choose any value in the codomain for each element in the domain; this gives $2^n$ to the power $2^n$ possibilities, that is, $({2^n})^{2^n} = 2^{n2^n}$.